# Text greek symbol not appearing with fontspec package

Tags: xetex, fontspec

What is the reason that `\textalpha` is not working when `fontspec` package is active?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \rm \textalpha
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Update**
I need to use `fontspec` package for the following reason.

```
\setsansfont[
BoldFont={Avenir Next LT Pro Bold},
ItalicFont={Avenir Next LT Pro Italic},
BoldItalicFont={Avenir Next LT Pro Bold Italic}
]{Avenir Next LT Pro}
```

Comment: Drop textgreek and use a (sans serif) font which has greek glyphs. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271665/2388